# Keep "this" context when mocking Promise in function on component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-test-renderer

I am having an issue where I am not able to reference `this` keyword via Jest when testing some logic in my `componentDidMount` method. So once I am inside the promise response, when I hover over `this` in `this.props` (or this.setState), it just shows `undefined`.

This is the Method in my App component:

```
componentDidMount() {
  myHttpService.getUser(this.props.userId).then(response => {
    if (response.user !== null) {
      this.setState({ user: response.user });
    } else {
      this.props.history.push('/login');
    }
  });
}
```

This is my unit test for that component:

```
it('push login route to history if no user is returned', () => {
  myHttpService.default.getUser = jest.fn(() =>
    Promise.resolve({ user: null }),
  );

  const result = renderer.create(
    <MemoryRouter>
      <App />
    </MemoryRouter>,
  );

  // Not sure how to check that route was pushed to history, trying to solve the this context issue first.
  // expect(?).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: I think what you mean in the question is `this.state` not `this.setState`, right?

Comment: @konekoya I meant the this keyword in the .then scope of the promise return.  So where i pass in this.props.userId to the function on the service, when I hover over the this keyword I am able to see all the properties on the class like expected.  When I am in the scope of the then, the this keyword becomes undefined.  Not sure how to pass the class context to be referenced with "this" in that .then scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mock the service in your test file

```
jest.mock('<path-to-your myHttpService>', () => {
  return function() {
    return { getUser: () => Promise.resolve({ user: null }) };
  };
});
```

You can do the following for the assertion with Jest

```
let instance = result.getInstance();
let history = instance.history;
expect(history.location.pathname).to.equal('/login');
```

Here is a complete working repo on [github](https://github.com/GSSwain/react-router-unit-test-example)

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, I tried the first way (The one you have not tried) and still had the same issue where "this" is undefined.  I also tried the jest.mock way you provided and when I stepped through the code, it still attempts to use the real myHttpService and breaks, is there something I have to do in the unit test to have this mock applied to the class?  Or maybe because it's a default export in the myHttpService something is not working correctly.

Comment: @Shawn I have updated the answer with a repo using the react-router-dom MemoryRouter.